# How do I print elements in a Python list one by one?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list in Python like this:

`x = ["1","2","3","4","5"]`

...how can I get it to print 1 and then 2 and then 3 and so on and so forth?

Comment: Are you familiar with `for` loops?

Comment: You might want to read [`for` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Although this sounds suspiciously like a homework assignment you're asking for help with, you could do this using a For loop:

```
for num in x:
     print(num)
```

You iterate through the list using a For loop, and print each element in the list which becomes a step in the iteration process.

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: The question came from a beginner so please use the correct terms. This is not an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) but a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

Comment: @Matthias - wrote it fast. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for` loop, explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

```py
for y in x:
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [for loop](https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/).

```
for number in x:
     print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sep= parameter of the print function with unpacking and a new line as separator value:

```
print(*x,sep="\n")

1
2
3
4
5
```